# How to carry interaction over "ancilla" particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, hamiltonian, interactions

Let's say we have just two particles that interact with each other according to some quantum Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$. Is it possible to add a third "ancilla" particle between the first two and reformulate the Hamiltonian, so that the initial interaction would be carried over the additional particle, but the overall physics would remain the same?

An example of such Hamiltonian could be the TFI model:

$$ \hat{H}= -J \sum_{i = 1}^{L-1} \hat{\sigma}_i^x \hat{\sigma}_{i + 1}^x - g \sum_{i=1}^{L} \hat{\sigma}_i^z,$$

where initially $L = 2$. Is it possible to add this "ancilla" particle and rewrite such a Hamiltonian, so that the energy of the whole system and correlations between the initial particles would remain the same?